# Do I need Xcode to publish a book in apple ibook store or not?

Tags: xcode, app-store

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

I would like to publish an eBook on ibook author.
So do i need Xcode to publish my book ?

If not, then how can i publish my book ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about ebook publishing, and is in no way programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need Xcode. XCode is an IDE which is used for programming. Publishing an Ebook does not require any programming.

You will need an Apple account and iTunes Producer for that.

From [Apple Support page for E-book publishers](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2808?locale=en_US):

> You can submit your book for publication on the iBooks Store, or
>   export it in a variety of formats and distribute it yourself. Before
>   you can publish to the iBooks Store, you need to do the following:
>
> - **Get an Apple ID** (a user name you can use to shop the iTunes Store, sign in to iCloud, and more). If you don’t have an Apple ID or aren’t
>     sure if you have one, go to the My Apple ID website. You must have a
>     valid credit card associated with your Apple ID on the iTunes Store.
> - **Enable iTunes Connect with your Apple ID**. You can do this for free during the publishing process (after you click Publish). When you
>     enable iTunes Connect, you choose whether you want to only offer books
>     for free, or both sell them and offer them for free.
> - **Download iTunes Producer**, the application you use to submit your book to the iBooks Store. You can download iTunes Producer for free as
>     part of the publishing process.
> - **Create a sample book** (required if you’re selling a book) for customers to view for free before deciding to purchase your book.
>     During the publishing process, iBooks Author can create a sample based
>     on one of your book’s chapters. Or you can create a sample manually.
>
> Books you sell on the iBooks Store can be protected by Apple’s
>   proprietary FairPlay DRM (digital rights management) system, which
>   helps prevent unauthorized duplication of your book. (Movies and audio
>   included in HTML5 widgets are not DRM-protected.)

Apple has also created a very [detailed tutorial on how to use iTunes Producer](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingiTunesProducerPaidBooks.pdf).